# Как сделать проверку на соответствие ID пользователей в Telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу довольно простого бота для телеграмма и мне требуется сделать кнопку, доступную только администратору какого-то конкретного канала. То есть бот должен проверить в хендлере, соответствует ли ID пользователя с ID администратора, находящегося в списке администраторов бота. В случае, если входит другой пользователь, бот должен отклонить запрос к администрированию.

Можно ли узнать, как прописать эту проверку?

Comment: `if один_id == другой_id: делаем_что_требуется`

Answer (score 0):

В начале кода добавляете переменную admin с вашим айди

```
admin = здесь ваш айди
```

дальше просто сверяете айди пользователя с admin

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["admin"])
def admin(message):
    if message.from_user.id == admin:
        # здесь ваша команда
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'вы не админ')
```